# Client-PC to Home-PC

Tags: python, ajax

Any method for the client-pc to directly contact the home-pc to exchange or give data to a python script in the home-pc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://twistedmatrix.com

Although without more information in terms of what you're trying to do exactly, it'll be hard to help further.

Twisted should give you the framework you need to build a solid networked environment in Python though.

Comment: I am trying to get data whenever the client does a action. This data is supposed to be read by my home-pc.
For example, if the user presses 'S' i want to send ':S' to the home-python script which will read and take the process ahead.